# Using withTrashed with relationships in Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Is there a way to use `withTrashed` with relationships in Eloquent.

What I need is this. I have table and model `Mark` and another table `User`. `User` has many `Mark` and `Mark` belongs to `User`. So I defined this in Eloquent models.

Now I need to get an instance of `Mark` that is soft deleted. This is not a problem if `User` isn't soft deleted, but if both `Mark` and `User` are soft deleted, I get an error `Trying to get property of non-object`, because

```
$mark->user
```

won't return actual user, cause it is soft deleted.

Is there a way that I can do something like

```
$mark->withTrashed()->user
```

to get this related user even if it is deleted?

Answer (score 85):

Depending on your needs, you can define the relationship:

```
public function marks()
{
  return $this->hasMany('Mark')->withTrashed();
}

// then just
$user->marks;
```

or use it on the fly:

```
$user->marks()->withTrashed()->get();

// or when lazy/eager loading
$user = User::with(['marks' => function ($q) {
   $q->withTrashed();
}])->find($userId);
```

then your case would turn into:

```
$mark->user() // get relation object first
   ->withTrashed() // apply withTrashed on the relation query
   ->first();  // fetch the user

// alternatively you use getResults relation method
$mark->user()
   ->withTrashed()
   ->getResults();  // returns single model for belongsTo

$user->marks()->withTrashed()
   ->getResults(); // returns collection for hasMany
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this

Comment: This is a great answer!

Comment: I'm using the `protected $with` property. how will it work with this method?

Comment: @JunaidQadirShekhanzai don't use `$with`

Comment: Must we use `withTrashed` also with `belongsTo` ?

Answer (score 4):

You can do that like this:

```
$mark->withTrashed()->first()->user->withTrashed()->first()
```