# How to use softdelete withTrashed in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

I'm building an application in `laravel` where I've two models company and contact with belongs to relationship as following:

```
class Contact extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;

    public function company()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Company');
    }

}
```

I'm using softdeletes in company model too, Now suppose even if any company is deleted, I want the contact to be shown with there company details.

I'm trying to do something like this to retrieve the data:

```
$allData = Contact::with('company')->withTrashed()->get();
```

It is not working, it is only showing company details which are not deleted. Any ideas to overcome this problem?

Comment: Or of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25868025/using-withtrashed-with-relationships-in-eloquent

Comment: @ceejayoz yes first one helped while adding withTrashed to model.

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution:

- Contacts with trashed:

```php
$allСontacts = Contact::withTrashed()->get();
```

- Without:

```php
$contacts = Contact::all();
```

- Get companies:

```php
$companies = $contacts->company()->withTrashed()->get();
    
$allCompanies = $allСontacts->company()->withTrashed()->get();
```

Comment: Well in this solution I'll have to use `foreach` staement, any ways I got the solutions.